# Where is the complete William Hamilton's "Saints and Psychopaths"?

Tags: theravada, personal-practice, reference-request, enlightenment, meditation-recommendation

I have been trying to find a complete copy of William Hamilton's "Saints and Psychopaths" and although it seems to be distributed on the web in various places in electronic format, it also seems that every single electronic copy appears to be missing pages from the preface, specifically pages xiv and xv.  If you know where I can get these missing pages I would be extremely grateful to hear from you.  Unfortunately pretty much all of the hard copies available are prohibitively priced and I do not if there is a publishers for this book at present, in the book it appears to be "Dharma Audio Network Associates San Jacinto California 1995" and according to amazon the publisher is "Dana".

I have attempted to source a complete copy from documents.mx, www.buddhistische-gesellschaft-berlin.de, www.scribd.com, books.google.com & .co.uk, docsfiles.com, www.mediafire.com and various less reputable sites, but unfortunately to no avail.

Any assistance in tracking these pages, if not the full publication would be greatly appreciated, I also believe that a complete online copy of this title would be of considerable benefit to the world-wide buddhist community.

Comment: Are you seriously looking for two missing pages in the preface - and can't find $10 on a used paper copy, or you're just using this excuse to advertise a nice book? ;) I like people who are honest.

Comment: http://www.allbookstores.com/book/compare/9780964490406

Comment: Possible good if asking for a given copy and not only violate precepts but even laws by such. So be careful, not demanding and holding wrong views. Yet of course, merits and demerits ones own choices.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not know what you consider to be prohibitively priced, as of today, 6/7/2016, abebooks.com has a used copy for $34.95 plus $4.00 shipping. If the book is as scarce in hard copy as it appears to be, this seems to be a good price.

Answer (score 1):

The complete Saints & Psychopaths is available for free as HTML and epub here, https://github.com/eudoxos/saints. This includes the pages in the preface missing from the PDF copy.

Answer (score 0):

The first search result that showed up gave me [this PDF](http://www.buddhistische-gesellschaft-berlin.de/downloads/saints-and-psychopaths.pdf)... and it has the full preface.

Comment: It looks like that's missing pages xiv and xv.

Comment: Huh that's true... It seems like the author specifically took out those two pages of his personal background in the sangha.. It is the major one in circulation, too..